# Проблема с подключением API яндекс карт

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытаюсь подключить API яндекс карт в head:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>site</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/postscribe/2.0.8/postscribe.min.js">
      <script  async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
          var map = new YMaps.Map(document.getElementById("YMapsID"));
          map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(59.938518, 30.323342), 10);
        };
      </script>
    </head>
```

body:

```
 <body>
<div class="map-block_map-item">
          <div id="YMapsID" style="width:100%;height:100%">
          </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Но при загрузке возникает ошибка:

*"It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened."*

Если убрать атрибут асинхронной загрузки скрипта, то возникает такая ошибка:

*A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/_YMaps.js?v=1.1.21-58, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details*

Подскажите, как лучше всего решить такую проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Старая APi, с новой все работает нормально https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/quick-start/tasks/quick-start-docpage/

А еще здесь

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/postscribe/2.0.8/postscribe.min.js">
```

был незакрытый тег